# Modify original UIImage in UIGraphicsContext

Tags: ios, uiimage, uikit, core-graphics

I've seen a lot of examples where ones get new UIImage with modifications from input UIImage. It looks like:

```
- (UIImage *)imageByDrawingCircleOnImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    // begin a graphics context of sufficient size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

    // draw original image into the context
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    // get the context for CoreGraphics
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draw there
```

I have similar problem, but I really want to modify input image. I suppose it would work faster since I would't draw original image every time. But I could not find any samples of it. How can I get image context of original image, where it's already drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImage` is immutable for numerous reasons (most of them around performance and memory). You must make a copy if you want to mess with it.

If you want a mutable image, just draw it into a context and keep using that context. You can create your own context using CGBitmapContextCreate.

That said, don't second-guess the system too much here. `UIImage` and Core Graphics have a lot of optimizations in them and there's a reason you see so many examples that copy the image. Don't "suppose it would work faster." You really have to profile it in your program.